# How to Handle Clickable Push Notification In One Signal iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

I already get the data from one signal (additional Data). But I want to present view controller by clicking the push notification itself. Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Did you check OneSignal's docs on Deep Linking? https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/links

There is a demo project on Github that might help you: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/tree/master/Examples

Comment: This https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/tree/master/Examples Help me.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
  this code will check that if app was launched using appIcon or tapping on notification

```
 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabBar = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigationController")
                as? UINavigationController


            self.window?.rootViewController = tabBar
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
if let notification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            // 2
            let aps = notification["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
            let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EmergencyRequestViewController") as? EmergencyRequestViewController
            tabBar?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
            }
        }
```